# preg_replace remove style text/css tag

Tags: php, html, css, regex, preg-replace

I need some help with my PHP as I have a hard time of getting rid of the `style type="text/css"` tag. I want to remove the style tag to replace it with the empty string.

When I try this:

```
if (strpos($inbox_message, '<style type="text/css">') !== false) {
    echo (preg_replace('/<style[^>]*>(([^<]|[<[^\/]|<\/[^s]|<\/s[^t])*)<\/style>/i','',$inbox_message));
}
```

It will still showing the style tag in the html page.

Here is what it is showing:

```
<style type="text/css"> body {position: relative; font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: 12px; } .pageHeader {color: #9C9C9C; font-size: 160%; padding: 0px 0px 6px 0px} .pageHeaderLogo {padding-right: 15px;} .pageHeaderTitle{border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 5px;} .pageFooter {width: 100%; background-color: #f2f2f2; font-size: 12px; font-family: Segoe UI; padding:4px 4px 4px 4px; } .pageFooterLogo {text-align:right; width:100%} .padCells { padding: 0px 6px 0px 0px; } .preHeader {display: none !important; visibility:hidden; opacity:0; color:transparent; height:0; width:0; }</style>
```

Can you please show me an example how I could use preg_replace to find the `style type=text/css` tag so I can be able to remove them?

Thank you.

**EDIT: Sorry I realised that I only need to remove the body in the style tags as I want to keep the other tags in the style.**

```
/*GENERAL*/
    table{width:100%}
    body{background-color:#ebebeb; width: 100%; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font-family: "Segoe UI",SegoeUI,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;}
    div.ms-article-container #emailbodyouter .emailbodyinner section{margin:0}
    div.ms-article-container #emailbodyouter .emailbodyinner table div {margin:0}
    div.content-article #emailbodyouter .emailbodyinner section{margin:0}
    div.content-article #emailbodyouter .emailbodyinner table div {margin:0}
```

Comment: `preg_replace` doesn't replace in place, you need to assign its output to the variable i.e. `$inbox_message = preg_replace('/<style[^>]*>(([^<]|[<[^\/]|<\/[^s]|<\/s[^t])*)<\/style>/i','',$inbox_message);`

Comment: Thank you, but it will remove all html tags in the page so it show as empty. I want to remove the tags between `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>`. Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to also remove the style tag itself?

Comment: @fromvega yes please. I want to remove it because it will change the body style so i want to remove it

Comment: I could use something like this `$inbox_message = str_replace('<style type="text/css"> body {position: relative; font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: 12px; } .pageHeader {color: #9C9C9C; font-size: 160%; padding: 0px 0px 6px 0px} .pageHeaderLogo {padding-right: 15px;} .pageHeaderTitle{border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 5px;} .pageFooter {width: 100%; background-color: #f2f2f2; font-size: 12px; font-family: Segoe UI; padding:4px 4px 4px 4px; } .pageFooterLogo {text-align:right; width:100%} .padCells { padding: 0px 6px 0px 0px; }`

Comment: @chrisoojer your problem is your regex is too greedy and it will match from the first `<style>` to the last `</style>`, removing everything in between

Comment: ` .preHeader {display: none !important; visibility:hidden; opacity:0; color:transparent; height:0; width:0; }</style>', '', $inbox_message);` but the style will be random so i want to use preg_match or preg_replace to remove the style tag itself that come with `style type=text/css`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Literal answer:

```
$inbox_message = preg_replace('#<style type="text/css">.*?</style>#s', '', $inbox_message);
```

You don't need to check whether it exists or not — if not, `preg_replace` will not do anything. You don't need to worry about what's inside the tag — the non-greedy quantifier takes care of it (as long as you don't by any chance have a nested `<style>` tag, which would be kind of extraordinary). And you don't need to worry about escaping slashes, if you choose another delimiter.

Non-literal answer: [Beware Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($inbox_message);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$styles = $xpath->query('//style[@type="text/css"]');
if ($styles) {
  foreach ($styles as $style) {
    $style->parentNode->removeChild($style);
  }
}
$inbox_message = $doc->saveHTML();
```

**EDIT** after the question changed: Since there is no CSS parser by default, we end up having to use regexp anyway. Something like this should be okay. Zalgo method:

```
$inbox_message = preg_replace_callback('#<style type="text/css">.*?</style>#s', function($match) {
  return preg_replace('#body\s*{(?:[^"}]|"[^"]*")*}#', '', $match[0]);
}, $inbox_message);
```

Anti-Zalgo method:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($inbox_message);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$styles = $xpath->query('//style[@type="text/css"]');
if ($styles) {
  foreach ($styles as $style) {
    $style->textContent = preg_replace('#body\s*{(?:[^"}]|"[^"]*")*}#', '', $style->textContent);
  }
}
$inbox_message = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for exactly as it is working great thanks

Comment: The `if ($styles)` would seem to be redundant as the `foreach` will do nothing  if it's empty

Comment: @Nick Yeah, probably being too defensive. `query` can return `FALSE`, but only if my query is malformed or the context is wrong (yet I believe the query is fine and I don't use the context)... :P

Comment: That's a fair point. Anyway, you get my vote for doing it the right way!

Comment: @Amadan Sorry to say that I only need to remove the `body {` so how I can do that using your code?

Comment: @Amadan I only need to remove this `body{background-color:#ebebeb; width: 100%; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font-family: "Segoe UI",SegoeUI,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;}` as it show on the bottom of the page

Comment: What do you mean, “show on the bottom of the page”? Styles aren’t shown, they’re applied. And after running my code, there shouldn’t be a style to apply any more (and certainly not show). What exactly are you asking? And, there was no talk about “body” in your question..?